# applying a text file to code

Tags: java

the problem, i'm having is i'm lost. i dont no where to start on this assignment.

this is what the text file looks like

the file name is "districtpopulation"

```
ALABAMA,Abbeville,2955

ALABAMA,Adamsville,4771

ALABAMA,Addison,720

ALABAMA,Alabaster,28904

ALABAMA,Alexander_City,15053

ALABAMA,Aliceville,2457

ALABAMA,Andalusia,8727

ALABAMA,Anniston,23736

ALABAMA,Arab,7694

ALABAMA,Ardmore,1145

ALABAMA,Ariton,747

ALABAMA,Ashford,1967

ALABAMA,Ashland,1856

ALABAMA,Ashville,2503

ALABAMA,Atmore,7452

ALABAMA,Auburn,53160

ALABAMA,Autaugaville,885

ALABAMA,Bay_Minette,7674

ALABAMA,Bayou_La_Batre,2761

ALABAMA,Bear_Creek,1016

ALABAMA,Berry,1212

ALABAMA,Bessemer,28217
```

The commands you must implement are:

•   average all

o   prints the average population of all districts to the console

•   average

o   prints the average population for the given state list to the console

•   top x all

o   prints the top x districts with the highest population for all districts to the console, x being any positive integer entered by the user

•   top x

o   Prints the top x districs with the highest population for each state in the state 
list to the console, x being any positive integer entered by the user

•   exit

o   Exits the program

Any command that accepts a  must perform the required action for each state in the list.  For example the command:

top 2 michigan new_york

should have the following output (the data is made up)

```
MICHIGAN:

            Detroit: 123453

            Flint: 4323532

        NEW_YORK:

            New_York_City: 2342342

            Some_other_city: 2342342
```

this is what me and a classmate put together

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Database {

    public static String[] data = new String[9000];
    public static int count;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean keepGoing = true;

        //other setup as needed


        while (keepGoing) {
            String command = keyboard.nextLine();
            String[] commandParts = command.split(" ");

            //if (commandParts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("average"))
                //if (commandParts.length == 2)   //do other stuff check for other things


             // else if ( . .. .) {


            //else if user entered in "exit"
            //keepgoing = fals      }

        //MiChIgAN == MICHIGAN 
        }
    }


    public static void readDataFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
        File dataFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(dataFile);

        while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
            data[count] = fileReader.nextLine();
            count++;
        }

        fileReader.close();

    }

    public static void topXAll(int x) {
        //print out the top x
    }

    //..top state
    // gettopforstate ..


    public static void averageAll() {
        System.out.println("my results here");
    }

    public static void averageList(String[] input) {
        String output = "";

        //for each state in state list {
            //output += getAverageForState(stateName);

        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static String getAverageForState(String stateName) {
        return "";
    }

    //this is how we do stuff
    public static void doStuff() {
        String[] parts;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            parts = data[i].split(",");
            String stateName = data[0];
            String districtName = data[1];
            int population = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you written any code for this yet? Also, which language are you using? You'll get voted down for seeming like you haven't tried to research this yourself at all..

Comment: Duuudeee.. We're not your employees, we won't do all the work for you. Especially if you're too lazy to write your own attempts first. Well, we'll gladly help you if you found a problem with your code though.

Comment: you need to do this in 3 languages? or are you skilled enough to translate from one to any other?

Comment: @user3059661 you probably best to delete the question yourself

Comment: What you have posted is not a question. It is an assignment. Try something first, then if you get stuck, ask a specific question about the aspect you're stuck on.

Comment: ok so it's a java, you should remove python and c++ tags then

Comment: my apologizes i didn't put my code on

Comment: Looks like you updated your question. Can you show what is exactly wrong with your current attempt? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `File` object and check `while(keyboard.hasNext() or hasNextLine())`, not check `while(keepgoing)`.  You should pass the `File` object as an argument the `Scanner`. `System.in` is passed when you want to read from the console.

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);

while (fileInput.hasNextLine()){
    String command = inputFile.nextLine();
    // do something
}
```

Also, I see this as a comment in your code `//MiChIgAN == MICHIGAN`. Make sure you don't fall into the infamous trap of trying to compare strings with `==`. Use `equals()`

**Edit:** 
Also, you probably want to split with a comma and not a space. There is no space delimiter between the text

```
String command = keyboard.nextLine();
String[] commandParts = command.split(",");
```

Comment: should i write a file object under the public static void main(String[] args) {

Comment: Yes, right above the `Scanner`

Comment: what do i do after that?

Comment: I don't know. What are you _trying_ to do?